# Google Drive Picker open in a new window

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, dropbox, picker

The Google Driver Picker always opens as a modal dialog ([here](http://stuff.dan.cx/js/filepicker/google/) is an example)

Is there any way to show the picker in a new window, just like the Dropbox Chooser ([example](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js))?

I was reading the [Google Picker Reference](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference), but I could not find anything. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why can't you simply open a new window in JavaScript that launches the picker?

Comment: I considered it, but I was thinking that perhaps there would have an undocumented parameter or anything to make it 'clean', without tricks. If there's no something like that, I will have to do it opening a new window :-(